# Как правильно выделять запятыми вводное слово в сложных предложениях

Tags: вводные-слова

1. Раввин Д. Лиор издал постановление, разрешающее ортодоксальным иудеям переходить дорогу на красный свет в случае необходимости — например по пути на молитву.

Грамота поясняет, что после тире стоит присоединительная конструкция, "например" вводит присоединительный оборот и потому запятая после "например" не требуется.

Но, с другой стороны, Розенталь в пункте о вводных словах пишет:

Дополнительный знак препинания может подчеркивать причинно-следственные или присоединительные отношения между частями предложения:

Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады (Пан.);

2. Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — должно быть, хочет зажечь огонь (Гл.).

И еще один ответ из Грамоты:

Правильно ли расставлены знаки в предложении: "Она хочет стать независимой, например просит подругу научить ее водить машину"?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

3. Она хочет стать независимой - например, просит подругу научить ее водить машину.

Не противоречивы ли эти рекомендации?

Ведь в предложениях 2-м и 3-м вводное слово стоит между однородными членами: "топчется", "хочет" и "хочет", "просит".

Но в одном случае перед тире есть запятая, а в другом нет.

Розенталь пишет, что перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям:

Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады (Пан.);

Непонятно, чем является часть после тире: "верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады", если Розенталь пишет, что "вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения".

Если есть три вида сложных предложений, то каким является это?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так: *Раввин Д. Лиор издал постановление, разрешающее ортодоксальным иудеям переходить дорогу на красный свет в случае необходимости — **например**, по пути на молитву.*

Присоединительная конструкция. **Тире** используется для обособления обстоятельства с уточняющим значением, вводное слово в его составе обособлено **запятой**.

Сравнить: *Раввин Д. Лиор издал постановление, разрешающее ортодоксальным иудеям переходить дорогу на красный свет в случае необходимости, **например по пути на молитву.***

Вводное слово входит в состав обособленного **запятой** обстоятельства.

**Пояснение**

1. Тема эта представляется мне очень **противоречивой,** а правила кажутся искусственными и надуманными. Нет в них убедительной логики.

Вот рассмотрим предложения:

*Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, **верно,** в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады*  (В. Панова).

*Бабушка уже топчется около стола, **должно быть**, хочет зажечь огонь* (Ф. Гладков).

Мы видим, что нет в оригиналах никакого тире.

2. И вот кажется мне, что пользователи в современных текстах ставят знаки препинания в подобных конструкциях **в рабочем порядке, согласно своему пониманию, а не по правилам.**

Самым "правильным" вариантом можно считать следующее предложение: *Она хочет стать независимой — **например,** просит подругу научить ее водить машину.*

Логика здесь такая. Тире следует использовать по назначению. В данном случае это обособление **присоединительных** конструкций (для однородных членов), а также **БСП** (для сложных предложений). Если в начале такой конструкции стоит вводное слово, то оно обособляется (ставится одна запятая). Запись четкая, всё предельно понятно.

3. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*То есть он обязан теперь жить по закону велосипеда: остановился ― **значит,** упал.*

*Знаете, как мы отличаем, чьи окопы нащупали? Пола нет ― **значит**, наши. У немцев полы были из досок от зарядных ящиков.*

*И он говорит, что их можно даже сильно улучшить ― **например**, убрать блики с воды или сделать ярче.*

4. А когда вводное слово **не обособляется?** Если следовать правилам 1956 года,то вводные слова могут выступать в роли присоединительных союзов перед оборотами, обособленными **запятой**: *Многие наши поэты, **например Жуковский**, были отличными переводчиками.*

Вот это классика, а все другие правила можно отнести к последующим доработкам темы, часто не очень убедительным.